# Billiard - how many times the ball hits the wall

Tags: c++, algorithm

I can't check how many times the ball in billiard table hits the wall, if it starts from left-up corner and has to reach the right-up corner.

This code gives me error for large numbers as `N,M > 1000`. Is there a way to optimize it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#define MAXN 101
using namespace std;


int main() {

    int m, n, k = 0; cin >> m >> n;
    int x = 0, f =0;

    while(1) {
        x += n;

        if(x == m) {
            break;
        }
        if(x > m) {
            x -= (x-m);
            f = 1;
        }
        k += 1;
    }
    cout << k << endl;

}
```

Comment: There's no `k`. BTW how is this program related to the problem described in the post, and how do I make sense of either?

Comment: The code shown gives _no_ hints what anything coded is good for - `MAXN, main(), f, …`. Use telling names, comment the non-ovious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand anything in your code, but you don't need anything of this. This is well know problem and there is simple formula `(N / d + M / d) - 2`. Where `d = gcd(N, M)`.

You can read about that here: http://www.jstor.org/stable/3618914?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

And also your code is wrong. Did you write it yourself?